# How to check whether an Xpath is clickable?

Tags: selenium, plaintext

I have an application developed in Liferay. It has a data grid which has pagination.

When ever i open the data grid for the first time Prev is not clickable and Next is clickable. Below is the html code for the same.

```
    <section class="paginationArea">
    <div id="pager">
    <span id="prev" class="disablehyperlink"><< Previous Page</span>
    <span id="next" class="enablehyperlink">Next Page >></span>
    </div> 
    </section>
```

Please let me know how can i check whether that text is clickable or not??

Answer (score 1):

You can always check it for a class attribute (assuming class change will cause enabling the button). You didn't specify a language so I will show you example in Java.

```
Element prevButton = driver.getElement(By.id("prev"));
if(prevButton.getAttribute("class").equals("disablehyperlink") {
    // do something
}
```

or you can try `WebDriver#isEnabled` method but I don't know whether it will work because it depends how are you disabling the button

```
if(prevButton.isEnabled()) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, all the `<a> anchor Tags` will be clickable.

In your case, `Prev` is not clickable. Because prev [previous in paginator] is **hidden**; where else Next [next in paginator] is **not hidden**(enabled).

Use `Firebug` [firefox add-on] to track all the hidden  anchor tags | href links and code accordingly.